# Associate Stripe checkout session with subscription webhook

Tags: php, ide, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe to handle payments for a subscription service I'm setting up.

I gather the relevant information from my customer, then on the server side, I use the Stripe PHP IDE to set up a new customer and create a checkout session for a `price` object which I've set up as a subscription. I save the checkout session ID to my database, then use that same session ID client side to take payment from the customer, via a redirect to Stripe.

The webhook `checkout.session.completed`, then lets me link up the previous checkout session ID with the subscription ID. Then I need the second webhook `customer.subscription.updated` to get the status of the subscription from the subscription id.

It feels like I'm doing something wrong here. I'm using two webhooks to get the information I need. If the `checkout.session.completed` webhook were to arrive after the `customer.subscription.updated` webhook, then my logic will fail.

Is there a better/correct way to manage this flow?

Answer (score 5):

You only need `checkout.session.completed` here. That event indicates a successful Checkout and payment.

I would ignore the initial `customer.subscription.updated` event and instead, if you need that status, fetch the Subscription with https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/retrieve when you receive the `checkout.session.completed` event.

Comment: Thanks @cjav_dev, I was already part way though re-factoring as you've just described. Still seems a bit rubbish. If they just returned the full subscription object in the checkout.session.completed webhook, then I wouldn't need yet another trip across the network!

Comment: I hear ya, Checkout is used for many other things than subscriptions so including the right data there is tricky. Including more than the top level data can also be a bit heavy on the network when it's not always needed.